# Binary vector to string

Tags: string, matlab, vector, binary

I would like to convert a binary vector of 24 bits to a single string.

For example, I should get the string: `'101010101010101010101010'` from this vector: `[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]`

I tried this :

```
binary_vector = [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0];
A = num2str(binary_vector);
l = length(A);
```

And I obtain :

```
A =

1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0


l =

    70
```

What I don't understand is why my length of `A` is 70? Shouldn't be 24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
A = num2str(binary_vector,'%d')
or
A = sprintf('%d',binary_vector);

A = 101010101010101010101010
```

Comment: Great! I would have added an explanation as to why `num2str` adds 2 spaces, but to be honest, I have no idea why they did it that way.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are also including spaces in the final result.  beaker in his answer above suggested the proper way to do it using a format specifier with `num2str` or `sprintf`.  However, if your string just consists of `0/1`, another method I can suggest is to add 48 to all of your numbers, then cast with `char`:

```
A = char(binary_vector + 48);
```

The ASCII code for `0` and `1` is 48 and 49 respectively, so if you add 48 to all of the numbers, then use `char`, you would be representing each number as their ASCII equivalents, thus converting your number to a string of `0/1`.

Something more readable can be:

```
A = char(binary_vector + '0');
```

The `'0'` gets coalesced into its equivalent `double` value, which is 48 as that is the ASCII code for `0`.  When you add something to a `double`, which is what `binary_vector` is - a vector of `doubles`, the type gets converted to its equivalent `double` type.  It depends on your preference, but I use the first one out of habit because of code golfing.

We get:

```
>> A

A =

101010101010101010101010
```

Comment: I don't understand why padding the columns isn't a documented behavior.

Comment: @excaza I really don't know either to be honest.